# Using auto-fill or auto-fit in grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 200px) only sets the height for the first row - why is this?

Tags: css, css-grid

I wanted to set the row height for each row in a grid using `grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 200px)` but realised it only applies to the first row of the grid. Turns out `grid-auto-rows: 200px` was better suited for my needs, but I'd still like to know why using `auto-fill` in `grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 200px)` only sets the height for the first rows instead of all rows. Note: if I use an integer instead of `auto-fill` it correctly sets the height for the number of specified rows.

Image examples:

- [`grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 200px)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdqZr.png)
- [`grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 200px)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxwsM.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the specfication](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#auto-repeat):

> When `auto-fill` is given as the repetition number, if the grid container has a definite size or max size in the relevant axis, **then the number of repetitions is the largest possible positive integer that does not cause the grid to overflow its grid container** (treating each track as its max track sizing function if that is definite or as its minimum track sizing function otherwise, and taking gap into account); **if any number of repetitions would overflow, then 1 repetition.** Otherwise, if the grid container has a definite min size in the relevant axis, the number of repetitions is the smallest possible positive integer that fulfills that minimum requirement. Otherwise, **the specified track list repeats only once**.

It's a bit tricky but `auto-fill` is suitable for column definition because we have a max size since by default the element will be full width but it's not the case when dealing with row and height.

Unless you define an explicit height, you will most probably fall into the case of only one repetition like you are facing:

```css
.container {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows:repeat(auto-fill,200px);
  grid-gap:5px;
}

.container div {
   height:50px;
   background:red;
}

body {
  border:5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

The same will happen in a column definition when using `inline-grid`

```css
.container {
  display:inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fill,200px);
  grid-gap:5px;
}

.container div {
   height:50px;
   background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

As you already noticed, the correct way is to use `grid-auto-rows: 200px`

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense now. 

So given a container height of 500px and no spacing, `repeat(auto-fill, 100px)` and `repeat(5, 100px)` would have the same outcome because auto-fill would calculate that only 5 100px items will fit in a 500px container.

Comment: @tfu yes exactly, auto-fill will be converted to the *best* number that will avoid you any overflow. It's suitable for column layout to have a dynamic layout on resize but we rarely use it with rows. Probably there is a use case for rows but I don't have anyone in mind actually

Answer (score 1):

So upon my inspection, I realized that this occur because the height of the parent is not sufficient for every row to be at least 200px.
Make sure element have sufficient height and use **auto-fit** it worked for me.